# How to scroll text within a div to left when hovering the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text that does not fit in a `div` tag, `.textBox`. So I want to make a function that in case of hovering the parent div, the text starts scrolling from left to right. So the user can read the full content. And when it is not hovering it fades back to the default position.

I do not want to use marquee. I want do keep the structure as it is and use CSS, or JavaScript to solve it.

Here is an example without the function:

```css
.textBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox">Some Content here and some more here</div>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try using Marquee http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html

Comment: Marquee tag is deprecated.

Comment: And marquee tag is annoying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/JavaScript: How to stop marquee onload, and start on mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246132/html-javascript-how-to-stop-marquee-onload-and-start-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See this pure CSS solution, added a span tag to make it possible.

The key concept is: move the span tag to the left with the value of box's width - span's width. In the other word that makes it to scroll to the end of the text on hover.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tb68dwqr/)**

```css
.textBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.textBox span {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 1s;
}
.textBox:hover span {
  transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox"><span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>
```

Comment: This works excellent for outer elements with a fixed width. But what about elements with a dynamic width? For example, `.textBox` has its width set to `50%` or something. How would you apapt your solution to address this, still without any JavaScript?

Comment: @Flinsch Not sure currently, however you can take the answer and ask a new question with your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative version of [TheGuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884309/13935363) that incorporates javascript (avoids Jquery) to handle dynamic css width.

The transition for going back could be more sophisticated, but I figured it would only complicate the example.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mga8bh73/129/)**

```js
const tansitionTimePerPixel = 0.01;
const textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(
  ".textBox"
);
textBoxes.forEach((textBox) => {
  textBox.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    let textWidth = textBox.lastChild.clientWidth;
    let boxWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(textBox).width);
    let translateVal = Math.min(boxWidth - textWidth, 0);
    let translateTime = - tansitionTimePerPixel * translateVal + "s";
    textBox.lastChild.style.transitionDuration = translateTime;
    textBox.lastChild.style.transform = "translateX("+translateVal+"px)";
  })
  textBox.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    textBox.lastChild.style.transitionDuration = "0.3s";
    textBox.lastChild.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
  })
});
```

```css
.textBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.textBox > span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox"><span>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery scrollLeft method

```
var interval_val = 2;

setInterval(function(){
    $(".scroll_contant").scrollLeft(interval_val);
    interval_val++;
}, 100);
```

see this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/NtYpo6l77yet9SE0wpms?p=preview

and for demo example with onmouseover and onmouseout event visit : https://myswaasth.com/#/swaasth/procedures

Answer (score 1):

**SEE THIS BY JQUERY**

```js
 $(document).ready( function ()
        {
            // for stuff that scrolls left on hover
            $( ".scroll_on_hover" ).mouseover( function ()
            {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ellipsis" );
                var maxscroll =$( ".boardindex_themefitted_board_main_description" ).width();
                var speed = maxscroll * 15;
                $( this ).animate( {
                    scrollLeft: speed
                }, 10000, "linear" );//set timer for slower one
            } );

            $( ".scroll_on_hover" ).mouseout( function ()
            {
                $( this ).stop();
                $( this ).addClass( "ellipsis" );
                $( this ).animate( {
                    scrollLeft: 0
                }, 'fast' );
            } );
        } );
```

```css
   .boardindex_themefitted_board_main_description.scroll_on_hover:hover {  cursor: none;}
        .ellipsis {text-overflow: ellipsis;}
        .hide {display: none;}
        /* Set a fontsize that will look the same in all browsers. */
        body {background: #fff;background-repeat: repeat; font: 78%/130% "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif; margin: 0 auto;   }
        /* use dark grey for the text, leaving #000 for headers etc */
        body, td, th, tr {color: #444;}
        /* BoardIndex.template.php Theme Fitted format ------ */
        .boardindex_themefitted_category_holder_aligner {            text-align: center;            margin: 0 auto;        }
        .boardindex_themefitted_board_main {            background: #fff;            border: 1px solid #373737;            border-radius: 8px;            height: 44px;            margin: 0 auto;            width: 20%;        }
        .boardindex_themefitted_board_main_content {            padding: 10px;            overflow: hidden;        }
        .boardindex_themefitted_board_main_description {            white-space: nowrap;            overflow: hidden;            font-weight: bold;            font-size: 10px;            font-family: Arial;            color: #373737;            line-height: 12px;        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boardindex_themefitted_board_holder">
        <div class="boardindex_themefitted_board_main">
            <div class="boardindex_themefitted_board_main_content">
                <div id="boardindex_themefitted_board_main_content_chunk1" class="show">
                    <div class="boardindex_themefitted_board_main_subject floatleft ellipsis">
                        <a href="http://default-smf.visualpulse.net/index.php?board=1.0" name="b1">General Discussion</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="boardindex_themefitted_board_main_description scroll_on_hover ellipsis" id="input" >
                        Feel free to talk about anything and everything in this board.Feel free to talk about anything and everything in this board.Feel free to talk about anything and everything in this board.
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the value of 15 from?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I have taken out the CSS because it was unresponsive.  The following javascript code makes the `div` scroll when your mouse is over it.

**Please note:** I have added an `id="myDiv"` to the div in the html.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    myDiv.style = "overflow-y:scroll"
});
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    myDiv.style = "overflow-y:hidden"
});
```

I have also demonstrated it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/z57cnd2v/).

Comment: Thanks but there is no hover effect ?!

Comment: Sorry my first answer did not answer your question.  I hope this one is better.